# Attr com Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um aplicação onde clico na linha de uma tabela, o jquery pega o id da linha da tabela, monta uma **URL** e colocar dentro de um ***href=''***

O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar no IE o ***attr.()***, já testei no **chrome** e no **mozilla**, funciona normal, mas preciso que funcione no IE

PS.O aplicativo tem que rodar no IE, e na versão 8 !!!

***Tabela (vem de uma página externa via Ajax)***

```
foreach ($retorno as $valor) {
            $html.= "<tr class='codFuncionario' codigo=".$valor['codigo'].">";
                $html.= "<td>".$valor['nome']."</td>";
                $html.= "<td>".$valor['drt']."</td>";
                $html.= "<td>".$valor['cpf']."</td>";
                $html.= "<td>".$valor['setor']."</td>";
                $html.= "<td>".$valor['cargo']."</td>";
                $html.= "<td>".$valor['turno']."</td>";
            $html.= "</tr>";
        }
echo $html;
```

***Script***

```
$(document).on("click", ".codFuncionario", function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var codFuncionario = $(this).closest('tr').attr('codigo');
    //alert(codFuncionario);
    $(".a_registrar_digital").attr('href', 'registrar_digital.php?codigo='+codFuncionario);
});
```

***Html***

```
<a href'' class='a_registrar_difital' target='end_font' >Click Aqui</a>
```

Alguém aí já enfrentou o mesmo problema que eu e tem uma solução ???

Comment: Qual versão do jQuery você está usando? A 2.x não é compatível com IE8.

Comment: estou usando a 1.11.0

Comment: @Tafarel_Brayan Como é que está a testar se o `attr` funciona no IE8? Está a inspecionar com as ferramentas de desenvolvedor?

Comment: Pode colocar o seu HTML?

Comment: eu reformulei a pergunta colocando alguns outros dados...

Comment: @afsantos, sim estou usando a ferramenta para desenvolvedores nativo do IE (F12)

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho Internet Explorer 8 para tentar reproduzir o problema, mas deixo algumas dicas que podem estar na origem do problema.

---

O seu HTML tem alguns erros, embora me pareçam erros de copiar-colar para o Stack Overflow. Contudo, confirme se estão presentes no original.

```
<a href'' class='a_registrar_difital' target='end_font' >Click Aqui</a>
```

Falta um `=` no atributo `href`, e a classe tem `difital`, em vez de `digital` que o jQuery procura.

---

Existe [uma questão no SO internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14232661/2088822) em que o problema com o IE8 foi a ferramenta do desenvolvedor precisar de ser manualmente refrescada para mostrar as alterações no documento DOM.

---

Existe [outra questão no SO internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342903/2088822) em que se recomenda o uso de `HREF`, em vez de `href`, no jQuery. Penso que tenha a ver com o IE assumir o caminho como absoluto ou relativo ao domínio atual.

---

Em último caso, considere alterar a propriedade sem jQuery, conforme exemplo.

```
$(document).on("click", ".codFuncionario", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var codFuncionario = $(this).closest('tr').attr('codigo');
    var caminho = 'registrar_digital.php?codigo=' + codFuncionario;
    var as = $(".a_registrar_digital");
    var i = as.length;
    while (i--) {
        as[i].href = caminho;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso com attr o data-* atributos no IE o tempo todo, eu nunca tive um problema. [Aqui está uma versão online](http://jsbin.com/iyoqum/115/edit), apenas testado em IE6, IE7 e IE9. Não tem a minha caixa IE8 acessível, mas, novamente, eu nunca tive um problema.

> Fonte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052182/alternative-for-jquery-attr-in-ie

Comment: infelizmente não funciona no IE8, testei no 11 e pegou normal..mas preciso que seja no IE8, pq é um sistema para fábrica e o pessoal usam IE8 lá, e nem tentem mudar..rsr

Comment: "Não tem a minha caixa IE8 acessível"